# Python pandas: How can I collapse specific index levels in a pandas Multiindex while preserving other values of the index?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Multiindex pandas dataframe:

```
data = {'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]}
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('X', 'a', 'I'), ('X', 'b', 'II'), ('Y', 'a', 'III')], names=['Level1', 'Level2', 'Level3'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index)

                      A  B
Level1 Level2 Level3      
X      a      I       1  4
       b      II      2  5
Y      a      III     3  6
```

I would like to see the following outcome, concatenating Level1 and Level2 with '-' while preserving the values of Level3:

```
                       A  B
CombinedLevel Level3      
X - a         I        1  4
X - b         II       2  5
Y - a         III      3  6
```

I've tried various solutions with set_index() and lambda functions but they seem to either reset the entire index to the values in the final Level1 or throw KeyErrors. I've thought of unstacking the index, concatenating them across the columns and then stacking them again but I got an error somewhere along the lines of "KeyError: 'Requested level (CombinedLevel) does not match index name".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always convert [`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.to_frame.html) to make operations easier, then convert back with [`MultiIndex.from_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_frame.html):

```
tmp = df.index.to_frame()
tmp['CombinedLevel'] = tmp['Level1'] + ' - ' + tmp['Level2']

df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(tmp[['CombinedLevel', 'Level3']])
```

Alternatively with [`get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html) and [`from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html):

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.index.get_level_values('Level1') + ' - ' + df.index.get_level_values('Level2'),
                                      df.index.get_level_values('Level3')], names=['CombinedLevel', 'Level3'])
```

Or:

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([(df.index.get_level_values('Level1')
                                       + ' - ' +
                                       df.index.get_level_values('Level2')).rename('CombinedLevel'),
                                      df.index.get_level_values('Level3')])
```

Output:

```
                      A  B
CombinedLevel Level3      
X - a         I       1  4
X - b         II      2  5
Y - a         III     3  6
```

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprhension with [`MultiIndex.from_tuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html) and `f-strings`:

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(f'{a} - {b}', c) for a, b, c in df.index], 
                                     names=['CombinedLevel','Level3'])
print (df)
                      A  B
CombinedLevel Level3      
X - a         I       1  4
X - b         II      2  5
Y - a         III     3  6
```

Or use [`MultiIndex.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html) with [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html):

```
Level1 = df.index.get_level_values('Level1')
Level2 = df.index.get_level_values('Level2')
Level3 = df.index.get_level_values('Level3')

df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([Level1 + ' - ' + Level2, Level3], 
                                      names=['CombinedLevel','Level3'])
```

---

```
Level1 = df.index.get_level_values('Level1')
Level2 = df.index.get_level_values('Level2')
Level3 = df.index.get_level_values('Level3')

df.index = [Level1 + ' - ' + Level2, Level3]
df.index.names = ['CombinedLevel','Level3']

print (df)
                      A  B
CombinedLevel Level3      
X - a         I       1  4
X - b         II      2  5
Y - a         III     3  6
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this script after you compute `df`.

```
df = (df.reset_index()
            .assign(CombinedLevel=lambda x: x['Level1'] + ' - ' + x['Level2'])
            .set_index(['CombinedLevel', 'Level3'])
            .drop(columns=['Level1', 'Level2']))
```

Comment: Note that you can [`pop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) (`x.pop('Level1') + ' - ' + x.pop('Level2'])`) and you won't need to `drop` in the end ;)